# How to copy newly inserted records from local database to different database

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

We have a new development database setup on some server for our application. Currently we have a local database that we made use for testing our applications. Now we would like to move the newly inserted records in our local db to remote dev db.

Every colleague has their own set of records locally, so each one of us should be able to move their records. Planning to have a script that would help achieve this.

I know about "Insert into Select" but do not know how to use when source and target databases are different. Also how to consider dependent tables while doing the insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not just one single answer to your question.  You can perform this 'ETL' process manually or one can create an automated process to achieve the desired results.

**Database Link**

Oracle allows you to create what is called a [database link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm).  Take a look and see if this could be a path to achieve what you are looking to do.

**Export Import via Excel**

Otherwise a really manual approach is to export your data into an excel file... and then reimport the data into your other database.  If this is needed once or just a few times this approach is really quite simple.

You can import the excel file into it's own table and then after the data is in the desired database you can then write simple selects to INSERT the data where it needs to go.

The above are just two ideas... but the solution can become extremely complex depending on the 'system' that is required to perform the ETL operation.

Comment: Yes i tried Excel import and export, but in case where dependency on tables is more it becomes very tedious. Dependency in terms of foreign keys.

Comment: @sahananaik Yes certainly... when dealing with a medium to large database you must know your database table's dependencies.  The data you are loading must be loaded in the correct order so that when inserting records into a table that relies on data existing in other tables you must First load data into those tables.  For example... if a PERSON record has a corresponding ADDRESS Table... it would make perfect sense that in order to load records into the ADDRESS table a PERSON record MUST first Exist.  You should NEVER be allowed to load ADDRESS records without a link to the PERSON.

Comment: This Constraint aka Dependency is in place so that you don't accidentally end up with 100s or 1000s of Orphaned ADDRESS records in your ADDRESS Table without any link back to a PERSON.  Same goes if you were to attempt to DELETE a PERSON record.  The database should NOT allow you to DELETE a PERSON record without first DELETING all of the data that ties back to the PERSON... again to avoid Orphaned records.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try oracle replication , Oracle snapshot..
These things will help thanks
Also there are data guard solutions
I have not tried oracle streaming ..Oracle streaming too could work